# Refresh Token for Google Api Php Client

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, google-analytics-api

I am using the Google API Client to access Google Analytics. I want to access the data in offline mode, so I need a refresh token. How do I get a refresh_token?

Comment: Note: If your response from getAccessToken does not contain a refresh token even though you do it just as in smartcodes' example code you may need to revoke your application's access and start authentication (as a user) all over again because Google remembers earlier attempts and if you didn't give "offline" access earlier, you won't get it automatically later on. -> https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions

Comment: This comment is what saved my day ^^^ During local development, I couldn't find the refresh token anywhere and all I had to do was revoke the app and try again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try using the following code:

```
    <?php
        require_once 'apiClient.php';

        const REDIRECT_URL = 'INSERT YOUR REDIRECT URL HERE';
        const CLIENT_ID = 'INSERT YOUR CLIENT ID HERE';
        const CLIENT_SECRET = 'INSERT YOUR CLIENT SECRET';
        const ANALYTICS_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly';

        // Build a new client object to work with authorization.
        $client = new apiClient();
        $client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);
        $client->setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET);
        $client->setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URL);
        $client->setScopes(array(ANALYTICS_SCOPE));
        $client->setAccessType('offline');
        $auth = $client->authenticate();


        if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
           $token = $client->getAccessToken();
           $authObj = json_decode($token);
           $refreshToken = $authObj->refresh_token;
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: How about all this Function,
if (isset($_GET['code'])) { 
 
$client->authenticate();  

$_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken(); 


$redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];  

header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

}


if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {  

$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);

print_r($_SESSION['token']);

}

Comment: if (!$client->getAccessToken()){
 $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();  
 print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";

} else{    
 // Create analytics service object. See next step below.
 $analytics = new Google_AnalyticsService($client);
 runMainDemo($analytics);
}

any hint where am I suppose to put your function or should I modify one of these functions, any help will be highly appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

For PHP SDK of Google Client v2:

```
php composer.phar require google/apiclient:^2.0
```

You can try the PHP code to refresh accessToken as following:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ . '/client_secret.json');
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
  Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY)
));

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('YOUR APPLICATION NAME');
$client->setScopes(SCOPES);
$client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
$client->setAccessType('offline');

// Input AccessToken from such as session or database 
$accessToken = json_decode('YOUR CURRENT ACEESS TOKEN');

$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

// Refresh the token if it's expired.
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    // Get RefreshToken as json which can be reused
    $refreshToken = json_encode($client->getAccessToken());
}
```

---

#### Offline access issue

In addition, if you want to keep the existing behavior in your server-side applications, you need to set `approval_prompt` to `force`, otherwise you may get NULL returned from getRefreshToken(), which Google document doesn't mention:

```
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
```

> Referring [Upcoming changes to OAuth 2.0 endpoint](http://googlecode.blogspot.tw/2011/10/upcoming-changes-to-oauth-20-endpoint.html)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning about setApprovalPrompt() step. I finally got refresh token.