# Using the GoogleAPI's OAuth gives 'invalid_grant'

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

I'm creating an internal application in PHP that uses the Google Analytics reporting API.
The application will always use the same Google account to connect to Analytics, so I would like to just keep access- and refresh-tokens in my database.

I used the following [Google tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) to set up OAuth. I took the following steps:

**Bootstrap Code (for every step)**

```
$client = new apiClient();
$client->setApplicationName("Stat-robot");
$client->setApprovalPrompt("force");            
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setClientId("CLIENT_ID");
$client->setClientSecret("CLIENT_SECRET");
$client->setDeveloperKey("DEV_KEY");
$client->setRedirectUri("http://localhost/statistics/api");
$client->setScopes("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly");
```

**Step 1**

```
Redirect to the URL retrieved from $client->createAuthUrl())
```

**Step 2**

```
//Get a redirect from Google with a GET-variable 'code'
$client->authenticate();
$accessToken = $client->getAccessToken
//This gives me a JSON-format access-token
```

**Step 3**

```
//Set the access token retrieved in previous request
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
//set the refresh token from the JSON response
$client->refreshToken($refreshToken);
```

Now, the last part (`refreshToken`) gives me an error: **invalid_grant**.
I've read on SO and the rest of the internets, that I should set my access type to `offline` and my approval prompt to `force`. But I think I have (looking at the above).

So what goes wrong?

**EDIT:** I was reading through the source of the Google API itself. The `sign()` method from the OAuth class specifies the following:

```
if ($expired) {
    if (! array_key_exists('refresh_token', $this->accessToken)) {
        throw new apiAuthException("The OAuth 2.0 access token has expired, "
            . "and a refresh token is not available. Refresh tokens are not "
            . "returned for responses that were auto-approved.");
      }
      $this->refreshToken($this->accessToken['refresh_token']);
    }
}
```

So there's really no need to call `$client->refreshToken()`

Comment: Looks like an error message/code. Check the vendors documentation when that message is given and compare with your code.

Comment: You're quite right. But the vendor says I should add `access_type=offline`. Which I think I did

Comment: Well, I didn't spoke about third parties, I spoke about the vendor. What does the vendor (Google Inc.) say about that error code?

Comment: The vendor (Being [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/gdataLibraries)) doesn't discuss this error in its [Documentation about refresh tokens](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#refresh)

Comment: Contact their support and report the issue that you're missing information.

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168098/refresh-token-for-google-api-php-client Seems like you have to fetch and store the refresh token yourself from the response JSON of `getAccessToken()`.

Answer (score 0):

For resolving of the received error **"invalid_grant"** , google advice to update your server clock also, check if you reached the maximum of api calls.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved invalid_grant error by changing the scope...

googleapi.authorize({
                    client_id : 'YOUR CLIENT ID',
                    client_secret : 'YOUR CLIENT SECRET',
                    redirect_uri : ' ',
                    scope : 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
                             https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
                    }).done(function(data) {

```
            });
```