# PHP Google Analytics server to server OAuth get Refresh Token

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client, service-accounts

I'm trying to get a `refresh token` from Google's authentication server for use with the Google Analytics API in a server side authentication with a `Service Account Credential` using the official [Google PHP client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client).

I'm able to create a `access token` and use that but currently I create a new token every time a user enters the page. I would like to decrease our traffic and get a refresh token to pass it to my JavaScript function.

```
gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    serverAuth: {
        access_token: accessToken <-refresh token is that even possible?
    }
});
```

My current PHP code is:

```
$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Craft CMS Plugin");
$client->setAuthConfig($credentialPath);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);

$client->refreshTokenWithAssertion();

$this->analyticsAccount = new \Google_Service_Analytics($client);
$token = $client->getAccessToken();
$accessToken = $token['access_token'];
```

But there is no refresh_token. I can `var_dump`everything but I only find the access token. I already tried this [Refresh Token for Google Api Php Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168098/refresh-token-for-google-api-php-client) but it didn't work.

Can you please help me? How can I get one.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Service accounts work differently than Oauth2.  They don't have refresh Tokens.
2. JavaScript doesn't have the power to use Refresh Tokens.
3. Why are you worried about traffic the service account should only be requesting authentication when it needs it once an hour.  As far as traffic is concerned I would think this is minor.

Answer what you want to do is not possible if the service account is working leave it.

Comment: Thank you very much, so I'll store my access token and use that one. Could you please tell me if there is a better way to check if the token is still valid than comparing the times? I would store my token + the current time in my database and check if 3600s have passed. Sorry if that is a stupid question but I'm relative new to this

Comment: you shouldn't be the client library takes care of that for you.

Comment: what do you mean by that? I have to check if the access token is still valid if I get it from my database before I send it to my javascript function. If I don't do that there will be an error.

Comment: Seems overkill storing an access token in the database. But I guess I don't know how you system is set up

Comment: I'm using Craft CMS and create a plugin if that helps you and my boss said I should store the token

Comment: But my question still exists: if I store it somewhere else is there a better way to check if its valid or not? `$client->isAccessTokenExpired()` returns always true now matter what

Comment: Not that I know of.  Besides just sending a dummy request and waiting for it to come back with an error.  Or store a time in the db as well and check time wait 55 minutes and request a new one that is what the client library is doing in the back end

Comment: Is it me or is `isAccessTokenExpired()` buggy? If `'created'` key does not exist(and It doesn't, var_dump'ed and nada) it will always return `true`...

Comment: It's not buggy if you don't have a `created` date you can't tell if its expired or not, this function just compares the `created` with the current date and returns the solution. The `bug`appears sooner since you don't receive a created date with your token. If you `var_dump` your received token, you'll notice you only have a lifetime (3600) a type and the token itself and no create time...Just store the time yourself together with your token and everything will work